# php 7 - "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest" - out of nowhere

Tags: php, ajax, nginx

I spent many time for this case, but i can't understand how it arises.
So. I have legacy php application. 
Now it is working on the following environment:

```
PHP 5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Zend Engine v2.6.0 with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev

nginx/1.4.6
```

For test i setup php-7

```
PHP 7.0.0RC3 (cli) 
Zend Engine v3.0.0-dev, with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev

nginx/1.4.6
```

So, case.
I load page first time:
http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0929/h_1443537572_8408994_b7e2156e5f.png

After page loaded, executed several ajax requests.

After reload page, in the $_SERVER variable we have **HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH**
http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0929/h_1443538095_6543758_9b4a478a13.png

but as you can see in the request headers we havn't this header.
Below you can see headers from nginx (access log)

Ajax request

```
10.0.2.2 - - [29/Sep/2015:15:00:44 +0300] "GET /stat/notifications-count HTTP/1.1" 200 30341 "http://vm-hub.dev:8888/client" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "-" "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" "XMLHttpRequest"
```

and normal request

```
10.0.2.2 - - [29/Sep/2015:15:14:32 +0300] "GET /client HTTP/1.1" 200 95434 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "-" "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" "-"
```

So: browser doesn't send this header. Nginx doesn't see and doesn't send this header too. But in $_SERVER this header is present.

I create small php sript which only dump $_SERVER variable. And after above case i run it from browser
http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/15/0929/h_1443538918_1985783_dcff1bacfb.png

and there HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH present to.

I can't define - is this php bug or other soft bug.

can anyone give some advice?

Maybe somebody from php team read this question and can comment this case?

PHP installed from here: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0
and some modules compiled manually.

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    client_max_body_size 200M;


        log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$sent_http_cache_control" "$http_x_requested_with"';



    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

site.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vm-hub.dev www.vm-hub.dev;

    root /media/sf_data/projects/hub/html/hub/public;
    index index.php;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    error_log /media/sf_data/projects/hub/html/hub/log/error.log;
    access_log /media/sf_data/projects/hub/html/hub/log/access.log main;

    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location @rewriteapp {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /media/sf_data/projects/hub/html/hub/public/index.php;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_param  APPLICATION_ENV dev;
    }
}
```

**Important:** This application worked on production on the same version Ubuntu, nginx, mysql. Different only PHP version.
Thats why i think that the problem in php.

**Update1. More details about problem**
In the application we have following code

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return new JsonResponse([/*any data*/]);
} else {
    return new Response('tempalte render');
}
```

Request and Response (JsonResponse) - this is Symfony HttpFoundation component.
So, when i'm first time load page - template rendered. But when i'm reload page, request defined as AJAX, and return JsonResponse. 
But this behavior is permanent. Now i can't determine the conditions when it arises.

**Update 2.**
When i catch this error i try:

1. Restart nginx - nothing changed.
2. Restart php-fpm - error disappears

So, everything indicates that the error occurs in php.

**UPDATE 3 - Guilty.**

I think guilty is - fastcgi_finish_request();
Below you can find test script to check this behavior.
I test it on:

1. PHP7 RC3 - bug is present
2. PHP 5.6.13 - bug is absent

[test script gist](https://gist.github.com/madmis/313f99b45b23b506a6e6)

Comment: Did you change your browser as well?

Comment: That header doesn't look like it's for the same URL. The request URL is `http://vm-hub.dev:8888/client`, but `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is `/media/sf_data/project/hub/html/hub/public/index.php`.

Comment: I'm confused? Your ajax request is sending the header? Your normal request is not sending the header. Is the screenshot from ajax request or the normal http request?

Comment: **honerlawd** all screenshots rom normal requests.

Comment: **Barmar** this is symfony components with symfony routing

Comment: @Dmitry To send a comment to someone, put @ before their name. Just typing the name normally (or in bold) doesn't notify them of the comment.

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, but this is not browser problem. In the question is show nginx access_log with headers. And normal request doesn't contain  HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header.http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/15/0929/h_1443540463_1332434_efc2a3afa7.png

Comment: @Barmar, i understand. Thank you.

Comment: jQuery sends this header for AJAX requests

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes, i know. But as you can see here http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0929/h_1443538095_6543758_9b4a478a13.png this is not ajax (jquery) request. And in the browser headers - this header is absent.

Comment: may be php sends some cached page?

Comment: General problem - in normal request (not ajax, without any ajax header) - in result $_SERVER variable HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header is present. And i can't understand - how it's possible. I think this is php7 RC3 bug, but i'm not shure. And i can't create bug here - bugs.php.net - without proof.

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes, i think problem possibly in some caching system. But i don't know -  is php cache requests? and how php define $_SERVER[HTTP_]?

Comment: Dunno about the rest of you, but I can't really work out from the question what has been requested when, or what screenshots relate to which comment. It's already said in the question that there are some AJAX requests..., are we sure those aren't the ones in question? And does the black bar at the top of a couple of the screenshots mean anything? Entire thing just seems confused...

Comment: @JonStirling sorry, the question is bad. But i don't know how to formulate it more correctly. Black bar - this is var_dump($_SERVER).

Comment: @Dmitry My only suggestion in this instance is to put together a minimum viable test case that would allow us to replicate and see the issue ourselves, at least then we'd all be on the same page.

Comment: Start with nginx's full server config

Comment: @AlexeyTen i provide nginx configs in the question.

Comment: Anybody here? Can you test this behavior? - this is test script - https://gist.github.com/madmis/313f99b45b23b506a6e6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is was bug in RC3.
Fixed in RC4

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70607